# Laravel Config::set() does not seem to work with Queued Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

1. I need to modify the mail SMTP parameters such as `MAIL_HOST` and `MAIL_USERNAME` dynamically.
2. For, this I am using `Config::set()` to set these values dynamically.

```php
# This code works 
Config::set('mail.host', 'smtp.gmail.com');
Mail::to('user@example.com')->send(new myMailable());
```

3. The above code works if I do not queue the mail.
4. The moment I queue it, it appears that `Config::set()` fails to set the values.

#### Test to confirm `Config::set()` not working with queued jobs -

I created a simple job and put the below code in the handler.

```php
public function handle()
{
    # set the config
    Config::set('mail.host', 'smtp.gmail.com');

    # confirm config has been set correctly
    logger('Setting host to = [' . config('mail.host') . ']');
}
```

The above code creates the below log entry.

`Setting host to = []`

Why can I not change the `Config` on-the-fly for queued jobs? And how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Queue worker doesn't use the current request. It is a stand-alone process, not being interferred by config settings.

To let this work, you need to use a Job. The dispatch function takes your data and sends it through to the job itself. From your controller, call:

```
JobName::dispatch($user, $settings);
```

In the job you set the variables accordingly:

```
public function __construct($user, $settings)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->settings = $settings;
}
```

Then in the **handle** method:

```
\Notification::sendNow($this->user, new Notification($this->settings));
```

You can use a normal notification for this.
Do not for get to add **implements ShouldQueue** to your job!

Comment: Even though this question is a few months old, thank you very much for getting back to me on this. I will try this in my next project.